# Join pandas series of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'defg', 'hwer', 'qwerty'], 'col2': ['123', '456', '890', '90'],
                  'col3': ['knlk', 'knl', 'op', 'tui']})
```

And I want to join the strings from each row by a specific character, I'm doing like this:

```
df['col4'] = df['col1'] + '_' + df['col2'] + '_' + df['col3']
```

But I have to keep repeating the `'_'`, is there a way to do something like:

```
df['col4'] = '_'.join([df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3']])
```

Comment: `df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)`

Comment: you can do : `df.agg('_'.join,1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df['col4'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply('_'.join)
df
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
df['new'] = df[['col2', 'col3']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: you can add ```col1``` to the list

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't' accept  two right answers and since @kederrac answered first I will give him the right answer

Answer (score 2):

There is [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```py
df["col4"] = df[df.columns[0]].str.cat(df[df.columns[1:]], sep="_")
df
#      col1 col2  col3           col4
# 0     abc  123  knlk   abc_123_knlk
# 1    defg  456   knl   defg_456_knl
# 2    hwer  890    op    hwer_890_op
# 3  qwerty   90   tui  qwerty_90_tui
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Didn't know this string method existed

Comment: There's a whole host of `Series.str` methods, worth looking at!